# What is an exclusive RabbitMQ and why did one suddenly appear in our rabbit?

Tags: rabbitmq, queue

One of our rabbit servers has an 'exclusive' queue with an autogenerated name. What is it? What caused it to appear?

```
amq.gen-2HDvnQMGPUt72CDDFsNHQg  Excl
```

In the connections tab we have 2x rabbit@ connections with protocol Direct 0-9-1. What are are these connections? Why does this server have 2 of them and our other servers have only 1. It seems that one of these connections is responsible for the above Queue.

none           Direct 0-9-1            /
    none         Direct 0-9-1            /

We rebooted and it didn't go away.

Answer (score 0):

Your code must have declared a queue without a name and with the exclusive flag set. `amq.gen-` is the prefix for server-generated queue names. RabbitMQ won't create a queue on its own.

https://www.rabbitmq.com/queues.html